# Add Space in Field Names for STUFF with TSQL Concatenation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this code:

```
STUFF((
SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(colname) + ' AS ' +  DATENAME(month, colname) + ' ' + left(cast(colname as varchar),4)
from (SELECT DISTINCT date ColName FROM #data) y
ORDER BY colname
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
```

This returns an error because the space in between `DATENAME(month, colname)` and `left(cast(colname as varchar),4)` is causing the field name to be invalid. I tried adding double single quotes before and after `DATENAME(month, colname) + ' ' + left(cast(colname as varchar),4)`, but nothing changes. How do I add a space to this STUFF function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just want to escape the name?

```
STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(colname) + ' AS [' + DATENAME(month, colname) + ' ' + left(cast(colname as varchar(255)),4) + ']'
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT date ColName FROM #data) y
ORDER BY colname
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'
      ), 1, 1, ''
     )
```